# Determine if a user exists on ESXi (Busybox)

Tags: linux, shell-script, esxi, busybox

I'm writing a shell script in which I need to check if a given user exists. On most Linux systems, I can use:

```
id -u ${USER} 2>&1 || die "User ${USER} not found"
```

or

```
getent passwd ${USER} 2>&1 || die "User ${USER} not found"
```

However, ESXi 6 (which uses the Busybox shell, if that matters) does *not* have either the `id` or `getent` available.

I realise I could just parse `/etc/passwd`, but that won't work if LDAP authentication is enabled.

What command can I use to determine if a user exists (by username) on VMware ESXi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct command to get user.But you can use

```bash
esxcli system account list | grep {user}
```